# Could the equal amounts of positive and electric charge point to equal amounts of matter and anti-matter?

Tags: charge, antimatter, quarks, elementary-particles, leptons

The universe is electrically neutral because the electric charges of all quarks and leptons cancel.

If particles are electrically charged, then there are equal amounts of positive and negative electric charges in a collection of particles and their anti-particles.

Can we logically conclude that somehow electrically charged particles and anti-particles are distributed over the universal matter?

Answer (score 3):

I know we've had this discussion before, but...

- There is no logical reason why an electrically neutral clump of material must have an equal amount of matter and antimatter. It's perfectly possibly to imagine a thing made of an equal number of positive and negative matter particles, or of positive and negative anti-matter particles. Indeed, a chunk of coal is electrically neutral, because there are an equal number of protons and electrons. But there are *zero* anti-matter particles in a typical lump of coal.
- It is simply an observed fact about the Universe that there is more matter than antimatter. See, eg:

  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_asymmetry
  - https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-is-there-more-matter-than-antimatter/
  - https://home.cern/science/physics/matter-antimatter-asymmetry-problem
  - https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.76.1
  - https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/14/9/095012/pdf
  - https://inspirehep.net/literature?sort=mostrecent&size=25&page=1&q=find%20t%20matter%20antimatter%20asymmetry

If you want to propose that there are equal amounts of matter and antimatter, you have to explain in detail why your proposal is not immediately ruled out by the observational evidence from Big Bang Nucleosynthesis, the CMB and large scale structure, the absence of evidence of annihilation events in astronomy, and why matter is able to exist at all without being annihilated by anti-matter, as discussed in the above sources. Otherwise you are just ignoring experimental evidence which contradicts your personal prejudices, which is frankly against the entire spirit of science.

Comment: Well, I asked if it *could* be. It seems an incredible coincidence that quarks have precisely 1/3 or -2/3 of the electron charge and *all* of them together exactly cancel *all* electron charges. It seems logically to me that somehow there are positively charged particles and negatively charged anti-particles (say +1/3 and -1/3) distributed over them.

Comment: Which *could* be compatible electrons and up and down quarks only (so not their anti's).

Comment: The problem than would be though why there are electrons and ups and downs only, and no positrons and anti ups and downs.

Comment: @Felicia You are right to be surprised. There are research programs devoted to answering the kinds of questions you are asking in the comments (for example, grand unified theories might explain quantization of charge). But there are also clear experimental facts and it is unscientific to pursue a line of speculation that is simply in contradiction with experiment from the outset. Maybe you'll think of a way to evade the observational constraints, but you would need a very convincing and clear argument to get people to take this idea seriously, given the mountain of evidence against it.

Comment: Dunno... It *could* be that the charge of all electrons and down quarks is the antimatter part of that in all up quarks. I don't see any fundamental objection.

Comment: It could be, for example, what we *call* normal matter is actually equal amounts of both, so an antimatter universe (anti leptons and anti quarks) would contain the same as a normal universe. Maybe because our universe is left-handed, the only particles are leptons and quarks. But that's very non-mainstream. But somehow this seems closer to reality than the standard model.

Comment: "There is no logical reason why an electrically neutral clump of material must have an equal amount of matter and antimatter" But there also is no logical reason why they haven't.

Comment: I mean, how would it change observations?